# How do I apply javascript code sorted into html

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, sorting

So I have a html node for some tasks that user can create, when user clicks sort by date I want it to be sorted and changed in the html and other way round but I don't know how to do the html part, any ideas?

I can do the sorting in JS its really nothing hard but I just don't know how to apply the sort to html, maybe to store nodes into JavaScript variables and than clear the list of tasks and append child with sorted way?

Comment: post some code...

Comment: Post the code which you have tried

Comment: please provide more information and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input nodes need to be dynamic.
Ideally, you would use a framework like react which makes doing stuff like that really easy.
If you're using vanilla javascript then the easiest way (as you already suggested) would be to

- Clear the children of the parent node of list using methods like , `parent.innerHTML = ''` (there are better ways to clear the child nodes of parents, this is not a recommended way due to it not clearing any event listeners the child has)
- then re-rendering the list items once they have been ordered as per your convenience and appending them to the parent node using, `parent.append(child)` function

As an example 
Consider the html to be

```
<html>
  <div>
    <ul id="root-list-node">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="submit" onclick="submit()">
      order
    </button>
  </div>
</html>
```

and the associated js to be

```
let listItems = [
    {text: "item1", order: 2},
    {text: "item2", order: 1},
    {text: "item3", order: 3},
]

const renderList = () => {
    const listRoot = document.getElementById("root-list-node")
    listRoot.innerHTML = ''; //clear all children
    const listItemNodes = listItems.map((element) =>{
        // mapping each list item to a new node with <li> tag
        let listItemNode = document.createElement("li")
        listItemNode.textContent = element.text //populating the text in this tag
      return listItemNode
  })
  
  listRoot.append(...listItemNodes) //appending the li node to the ul parent tag

}
window.onload = () => {
    renderList()
}

submit = () => {
    listItems.sort((a,b) => {
    return a.order - b.order
  })
  renderList()
}
```

Here the `renderList` function loads the content in the HTML dynamically based on your listItems by deleting any child node the parent might have and then appending new child nodes, which is first done during `onload`. 
When you click the button to sort, it sorts the listItems array based on the `order` property, and then runs `renderList` again.

A working js fiddle can be found here https://jsfiddle.net/1Lwqtu8e/20/

Answer (score 0):

Create an HTML file with a .html extension (e.g., index.html).
Open the HTML file in a text editor or an integrated development environment (IDE).
Within the  section of the HTML file, add a  tag to include your JavaScript code. You can either write the JavaScript code directly within the  tag or reference an external JavaScript file using the src attribute.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain well, I have a whole to-do list website where user can add and remove tasks but I want the user to be able to sort the tasks by the date, so I want js code to change hierarchy of html code so its sorted right way